# keywords detection in pdf from latex

Tags: pdf, tex-core

I recently wrote my first LaTeX cv.

once I started to apply for jobs i notice that the tool them using to scan my CV doing some wrong classification like give me wrong name, or missing some skills I mention wich relevant for the possiton.
then few thought came up in mind.

1. what happened to the LaTeX doc after i built an pdf from it ? how they was able to find some inside command that not apper in the pdf? (like link to some guy GitHub who built the template)
2. how can i force some specific world to appear in the search ? like cover it under section "skils" or somthing like that?

to be honest I'm not really sure if its the right place to ask it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you want to ask. I don't think from your output PDF file can see the inside command in `tex` file. Unless you explicit write something to the PDF file properties. As far as i know, the way can do this is the `hyperref` package. You can set the title, author, subjects, keywords and creator field of your output PDF file properties. And these information can be seen by click the properties in file tab. For example, I am using Adobe Reader to check the PDF properties. Is this the place where the tool can gather information from PDF files?
I actually don't know.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdftitle={title},pdfauthor={nobody},pdfsubject={Example},pdfkeywords={test, example,nothing},pdfcreator={some body}}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Example}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]